# SUM ON two columns using Group BY and result on three Group BY

Tags: mysql

Hi want to calculate department wise applicant on the basics of ProgramOfStudy and Basis ID.
`SUM(TotalDepartmentApplicants )` This SUM should be calculated on thee Group By of ProgramOfStudy and Basis ID.

```
SELECT TotalApplicants.AdmID,AdmYear,D_ID,D_Name,TotalApplicants.BasisID,
TotalApplicants.ProgramOfStudy,TotalDepartmentApplicants,
 TotalDepartmentApplicants/ SUM(  TotalDepartmentApplicants   )
  As `DepartmentPercentage`
from TotalApplicants
INNER JOIN  BasisWiseApplicant ON BasisWiseApplicant.AdmID=TotalApplicants.AdmID  
GROUP BY D_ID, BasisID,ProgramOfStudy;
```

Comment: Please provide table description, some datas and expected result

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to divide the number of department applicants by the number of applicants containing a given BasisID & ProgramOfStudy. I'm not sure what your table looks like, so I will provide the alternative as well.

```sql
SELECT
    TotalApplicants.AdmID,
    AdmYear,
    D_ID,
    D_Name,
    TotalApplicants.BasisID,
    TotalApplicants.ProgramOfStudy,
    TotalDepartmentApplicants, 
    ( TotalDepartmentApplicants / 
        SUM(
            SELECT TotalDepartmentApplicants
            FROM TotalApplicants AS TotalApplicants2
            WHERE 
                TotalApplicants2.BasisID        = TotalApplicants.BasisID AND
                TotalApplicants2.ProgramOfStudy = TotalApplicants.ProgramOfStudy
            /*
            If they must be grouped instead replace the where clause with
            GROUP BY TotalApplicants2.BasisID, TotalApplicants2.ProgramOfStudy
            and replace TotalDepartmentApplicants with 
            sum(TotalDepartmentApplicants)
            */
        )
    ) AS `DepartmentPercentage`
FROM TotalApplicants
INNER JOIN  BasisWiseApplicant 
ON 
    BasisWiseApplicant.AdmID = TotalApplicants.AdmID  
GROUP BY 
    D_ID, BasisID, ProgramOfStudy
;
```